# issue with jquery .css() and getting brifed css of style Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to add style to an element using css() and save it
first step works fine but when i want to save it the code that jquery gives me is too detailed
for example

```
<div id="d"></div>

$('#d').css("border-radius","55px");
```

and

```
alert($('#d').attr('style'));
```

gives

```
border-top-left-radius: 55px;
border-top-right-radius:55px;
border-bottom-right-radius:55px;
border-bottom-left-radius:55px;
```

is there anyway to get less detailed code like

```
border-radius:55px
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with different method by capturing all input[type=text] where i set value of properties ,there  i can have full control on output

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert($('#d').attr('style'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see it by:

```
    $('#d').css("border-radius");
```

Or may be

```
    $('#d').attr("style");
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
alert($('#d').css(border-radius'));
```

Comment: the problem is i want to get all css properties in attr('style')

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Firefox and I got:

```
border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
```

In other browsers tested I got what you wrote. The output appears to be browser-specific - if you inspect the element in the DOM, even there it's already written differently in Firefox than the other browsers I tested (Safari, Chrome, Opera all write the explicit, extended definition).

Also found this, although in a different context:

> Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but
>   not textually equal, e.g.,  #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).
>   http://api.jquery.com/css/

In conclusion, if you want the style definitions in a specific formatting, you will have to do something like regex-replacing on the string that `attr('style')` returns. Hope this helps.